# What exactly does the BeanManager in java enterprise do?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In spring, I can use the application context to create beans dynamically.

Searching for some code to do something similar in java enterprise, I ran across the following snippet of code:

```
public class BeanManagingUtils {

    private BeanManager beanManager;

    public BeanManagingUtils()
    {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            beanManager =  (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            //log.error("Couldn't get BeanManager through JNDI");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getContextualInstance(final Class<T> type)
    {
        T result = null;
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(type));
        if (bean != null)
        {
            CreationalContext<T> context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
            if (context != null)
            {
                result = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, type, context);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

By calling getContextualInstance with a class, I can get it (sort of) to generate a bean, but I've no idea what sort of a bean it's generating, eg whether it's a stateless ejb, a stateful ejb, a managed bean, etc. It seems to create it happily if the bean in question is not annotated at all, and gives an error if I annotate the bean with '@Stateful'. I don't understand the documentation on BeanManager here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html

Can anyone shed any light on what it is doing and what kind of beans it creates, or point me to fuller documentation?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that you can create EJBs this way. The EJB container controls the EJB lifecycle. Additionally, you would normally control the lifecycle of other managed beans by specifying their scope (@ RequestScoped, etc) and let CDI create them on demand at injection points.

Comment: Thank you. I've now figured out how to create EJBs dynamically, analagous to using the Spring ApplicationContext. You just have to get them from JNDI - every time you 'lookup' a stateful session bean, you actually get a FRESH copy, because the EJB Container gives you a fresh copy every time it's asked for a reference. Not entirely intuitive, but seems to work just fine..

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#beanmanager